# How can I display the value from a slider as Icons in a row using Listview(maybe .builder)?

Tags: flutter, listview, slider

right now I am trying to, as pointed out above, give an visual output from the value of an slider. The question in the application is: How many people attended? Than there should be a slider where you can select between 2-20. Based on how you are sliding, above, the numbers of people should be display as Icons (Icons.people_outline). It should be pretty simple, I just seem to be not experienced enough.
This is the code snippet:

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 20,
            width: 100,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _currentSliderValue.round(),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                  return Icon(Icons.people_outline);
                }

            ),
          ),
          Text(_currentSliderValue.round().toString()),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Slider(
              inactiveColor: Colors.white54,
              activeColor: Colors.white,
              value: _currentSliderValue,
              min: 2,
              max: 12,
              divisions: 10,
              label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
              onChanged: (double value) {
                setState(() {
                  _currentSliderValue = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ]),
```

Somehow, the icons are just not been displayed.
Thanks for any thoughts! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, your list is showing, the default scroll is vertical, just add: scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal to your ListView.
Also change the container width to width: double.infinity.

```
      Container(
        height: 20,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: _currentSliderValue.round(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Icon(
                Icons.people_outline,
                color: Colors.red,
              );
            }),
      ),
```